# I cannot solve these separable differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

There is no explanation in the book on how to solve these and I can't find any help online. Step-wise calculators also don't make sense.

(1) $y'=(y^2-1)x, \; y(0)=0$,

(2) $xy'=y^2-2y, \; y(1)=1 \; x\geq0$.

I'll post the question and write my attempts underneath straight after

Comment: Couldn't you do part (1) via separation of variables? I tried and it seemed to work

Comment: @JustWandering yeah I just realized what I did wrong and I'm gonna answer my own question, I'm just slow with latex

Comment: That's fairs, do you still need help with (2)?

Comment: yes I do! @JustWandering

Comment: I tried with separation of variables again and I must say it works the same way as the first part. lmk if you struggles with any part. (Also Kevin posted what I had in mind as well)

Comment: I eventually get to $ln\mid\frac{y-2}{y}\mid=ln\mid x\mid^2+C$. How do I simplify from here? Also, I seem to be unable to avoid dividing by 0.

Comment: Not sure if that is the correct expression? Dont you mean something like $\ln (x^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, note that you can re-write

\begin{align}
y' &= (y+1)(y-1)x \\
\implies \displaystyle \int \frac{dy}{(y+1)(y-1)} &= \int x dx
\end{align}
Whence
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{y-1} - \frac{1}{y+1}&= \int x dx
\end{align}
Thus
$$\ln\frac{y-1}{y+1} = x^2+C$$

Then high school algebra can assist in re-arranging to make $y$ the subject.

For the second DE this can be written on the right as $y(y-2)$ and upon finding partial fractions
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \int \frac{dy}{y(y-2)} &= \int \frac{1}{x}dx \\
\implies \frac{1}{2}\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{y-2}-\frac{1}{y} &= \int \frac{1}{x}dx \\
\implies \ln(y-2)-\ln y &= \ln x + C \\
\implies \ln \frac {y-2}{y} &= \ln x+C\\
\implies \ln \left( 1-\frac{2}{y} \right) &= \ln x +C
\end{align}

and the result follows.

Comment: why do you get 1/4?

Comment: Good spot, my partial fractions tripped me up. Corrected now.

Comment: Could you give me advice on how to go about with the second DE?

Comment: I'll edit in some pointers....

Comment: how come you don't need to add absolute value signs in the ln expressions? And how would you use the initial conditions now considering $y\neq0$?

Comment: You should really use absolute values you are right. I was in a hurry and trying to work at the same time.

Comment: Haha ni problem :) I really appreciate you taking time from your work to help!

Answer (score 0):

for (1)
First separating the variables and integrating both sides with respect to y and x respectively
$\int \frac{1}{y^2-1}dy=\int xdx$.

The RHS is trivial but the LHS needs partial fractions, so

$\frac{-1}{2}ln\mid y+1\mid+\frac{1}{2}ln\mid y-1\mid=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$.
Using log identity and getting rid of the ln function gives

$\frac{\mid y-1\mid}{\mid y+1\mid}=Ce^{x^2}$, because the RHS is positive and using the initial conditions we get

$\frac{y-1}{y+1}=Ce^{x^2} => C=-1$, algebraic manipulation eventually gives the solution:

$ y=\frac{1-e^{x^2}}{1+e^{x^2}}$.